# Javascript/nodejs ANSI support (Windows-1252)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for way how to create a export file for external application, which accepts diacritics encoding only in Windows-1252. User should be able to download file through web application and import it to external application. I am using nodejs at backend.

Problem is that nodejs do not support [encodings](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) not even similar to 1252, so special characters like ľščťžýáíé are problem. Is there some workaround or way how to create file at frontend(after AJAX request) in required encoding?

EDIT:

Encoding was poor specificated by application owner. As @robertklep said, windows-1252 was bad encoding. I tryed lot of different encodings and a proper one was a CP-1250. Using a iconv-lite I created this example solution.

total.js

```
const iconv = require('iconv-lite);

exports.install = function() {
    F.route('/route/to/export',  download, ['get']);
};

function download() {
    var self = this;
    var text = 'some important content on multiple lines';
    var content = iconv.encode(text, 'CP1250');
    return self.res.content(200, content, 'text/plain', true, {
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="export.txt"'
    });
}
```

frontend

```
$('#btn-export').on('click', function(){
    location.href = '/route/to/export';
});
```

This is working well for me, but can someone find out better solution for file transfer from backend?

Comment: You could use [`iconv-lite`](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite) or [`windows-1252`](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/windows-1252), but I'm pretty sure that some of the characters in your example don't even exist in that encoding.

Comment: I can format string with windows-1252, but if I create a file with fs.friteFile() I can only choose node.js supported formats, so I loose a windows-1252 encodings. I can send a formated string via ajax to frontend but I dont know how create file and keep an 1252 encoding.

Comment: fs.writeFile also accepts Buffer which has no encoding.

Comment: @robertklep Your are right, in specification I found only ANSI encoding, but I think they mean ISO8859-1, not a 1252(which not includes special characters I used in example). It means solution is easy, use a latin1 encoding in writeFile()....